# Convince apt-get *not* to use IPv6 method

Tags: apt, ipv6

The ISP I work at is setting up an internal IPv6 network in preparation for eventually connecting to the IPv6 internet. As a result, several of the servers in this network now try to connect to security.debian.org via its IPv6 address by default when running `apt-get update`, and that results in having to wait for a lengthy timeout whenever I'm downloading updates of any sort.

Is there a way to tell apt to either prefer IPv4 or ignore IPv6 altogether?

Comment: Shouldn't that return immediately with a routing failure?

Comment: No, it's entirely possible that their internal network has routing between multiple subnets (and hosts have an IPv6 default gateway) but no IPv6 connectivity to the outside world.

Comment: There's probably a way to set up [`/etc/gai.conf`](http://serverfault.com/questions/173309/what-determines-whether-the-fqdn-is-interpreted-as-ipv6-or-ipv4/177649#177649) so that `security.debian.org`'s A record are returned before the AAA record, but I don't know precisely what to put in that file.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - but shouldn't their network's default gateways know that there isn't external ipV6 connectivity and reject the outbound attempt at the edge pretty quickly? I think there's a network issue here as well as the question being asked.

Comment: Fixing the edge router/firewall/whatever is causing the problem is the "best" way to handle this. It _should_ be returning an ICMP destination unreachable packet. This is either not happening, or something is blocking it. Either way, the problem should be reported to your network people.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Add `-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true` when running `apt-get`.

If you want to make the setting persistent just create */etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4* and put `Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";` in it:

```
echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4
```

Config options `Acquire::ForceIPv4` and `Acquire::ForceIPv6` were added to version *0.9.7.9~exp1* (see [bug 611891](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=611891#35)) which is available since Ubuntu Saucy (released in October 2013) and Debian Jessie (released in April 2015).

Comment: Moving the "accepted" to this one; while the original 30-point answer is perfectly correct, it's applicable on a much broader scale while this provides the option to *just* restrict apt-get.

Comment: Please be properly descriptive in your answer.   -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true   is the addition to the command to allow a user to use ipv4

Comment: Answer updated following Kendrick's suggestion

Comment: I just tried: it also works in wheezy.

Comment: Judging from the rest of my `apt.conf` you need to write it like this: `Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";` (with double quotes)

Comment: Answer updated following mirabilos's suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Why `tee`? Why not just use standard redirect method?

Comment: @ZAB because if you don't have write access to the file, `sudo echo 'test' > file` wouldn't work because the redirection is executed with the user permissions

Comment: Just tried this on Debian 10 (buster) - no change in apt's behavior.   Using the `gai.conf` change in the answer below *did* work.

Answer (score 94):

As [Gilles says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method#comment12930_9940), use `gai.conf`. Notes:

1. This works at a much lower level (DNS and IP networking) than APT, so it will change how **all** your applications network--at least, all that use `getaddrinfo`.
2. Before editing your `gai.conf`, you should back it up, and also read it (don't worry, it's short). The edits below are probably already mentioned in your current file; if the current file indicates something different from what's mentioned below, you should probably prefer what's in your current file.

But if this is what you want (which it probably is), let's proceed. Say we have two hosts `www.he.net` and `www.ripe.net` :

```
$ host www.he.net
www.he.net is an alias for he.net.
he.net has address 216.218.186.2
he.net has IPv6 address 2001:470:0:76::2

$ host www.ripe.net
www.ripe.net has address 193.0.6.139
www.ripe.net has IPv6 address 2001:67c:2e8:22::c100:68b
```

**Case 1: prefer IPV4 for all hosts**

Append to `/etc/gai.conf` the following line:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

After saving the edited file (no need to restart), you should see networking apps (e.g., `telnet`) using IPV4: e.g.,

```
$ telnet www.ripe.net 81
Trying 193.0.6.139...
^C
$ telnet www.he.net 81
Trying 216.218.186.2...
```

**Case 2: prefer IPV6 for specific hosts**

If we want to prefer IPV6 only for `www.he.net` or its network, we can append a [mask/prefix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/STCMML8/com.ibm.storage.ts3500.doc/opg_3584_IPv4_IPv6_prefix_subnet_mask.html) for all, or just some part, of its IPV6 address to `/etc/gai.conf`. E.g., the following line:

```
precedence 2001:470::/32 100
```

(after saving the edited file) produces

```
$ telnet www.ripe.net 81
Trying 193.0.6.139...
^C
$ telnet www.he.net 81
Trying 2001:470:0:76::2...
^C
```

**Case 3: prefer IPV4 for specific hosts**

If we invert the mask will the reverse be true? According to @GrueMaster, appending

```
precedence 2001:470::/96 100
```

worked for him after disabling IPV6 for `security.ubuntu.com` (otherwise it stalls forever).

---

See also:

- http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/IPv6_Networking#Prefer_IPv4_over_IPv6 (archived @ https://web.archive.org/web/20180905053005/https://www.funtoo.org/IPv6_Networking#Prefer_IPv4_over_IPv6 )
- http://www.getipv6.info/index.php/Customer_problems_that_could_occur#GNU.2FLinux (archived @ https://web.archive.org/web/20180920175314/https://getipv6.info/display/IPv6/IPv6+Info+Home#GNU.2FLinux )

Comment: Perhaps summarize content in case the above links disappear?

Comment: So, what's the syntax to disable IPv6 for a particular name, or at least for a particular address (range)? If you add that to your post, it'll be the best answer here.

Comment: Thanks. I added 2 lines `#security.debian.org has IPv6 address 2610:148:1f10:3::73 \n
#security.debian.org has IPv6 address 2001:4f8:8:36::6 \n

precedence 2001:4f8::/96 100 \n
precedence 2610:148::/96 100
` to my /etc/gai.conf and apt-get update works perfect now.

Answer (score 11):

You could setup *apt-cacher-ng* on a spare machine to act as a proxy/cache for all of your hosts. You can force the configuration to only use specific hosts or use the /etc/hosts trick suggested by @badp on that one machine.

```
apt-get install apt-cacher-ng
```

Once you have apt-cache-ng setup you just need to drop the following line (with IP address/hostname altered to point at your cacher machine) in */etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90httpproxy*

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://[192.168.1.254]:3142"; };
```

I use that setup to reduce bandwidth usage but it should workaround your problem. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to directly disable ipv6 lookups for apt-get itself.

Comment: Still not a perfect solution, but as good as it's likely going to get. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

How about adding a line in `/etc/hosts` overriding the relevant addresses? e.g.,

```
130.89.149.226  ftp.debian.org      
195.20.242.89   security.debian.org
```

Comment: I'll save this solution for last if there turns out to be absolutely no other way; I *really* don't like cluttering `/etc/hosts` with IP addresses I don't own myself.

Comment: @Shadur Yes, I can totally see your point :)

Answer (score 5):

You could work around this by setting up a DNS proxy server that dropped ip6 responses.

Comment: Won't your local resolver still try to get the AAAA record? And time out?

Comment: That is not a thing I want to even consider doing.

Comment: .. this question is a decade old, did you ever solve the problem? Or deploy ip6?

Answer (score 2):

As of Oct 08th 2014, I had the same issue, trying to update debian behind a proxy on local network. In the hope it will be relevant to others, I post my response here. As others have mentioned, editing `/etc/hosts` is something one should be careful with.

But personally I just wanted to have the update done.

Content of /etc/apt/sources.list when doing the update (it was different before the update..):

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ testing main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ testing main

deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

Content of /etc/apt/apt.conf:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://192.168.1.10:7777/";
Acquire::http::Timeout "10";
Acquire::ftp::Timeout "10";
```

Addition to /etc/hosts:

```
#Workaround for making apt-get work (08-10-2014)
195.20.242.89 security.debian.org
130.89.148.12 ftp.debian.org
```

Now, running `apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade` as root worked well.

As mentioned in other answers, use, run host command on the domain to get the correct ip to insert in the hosts file.

Example:

```
$ host ftp.debian.org
ftp.debian.org has address 130.89.148.12
```

This successfully updated the system to `Debian GNU/Linux testing (jessie)`. You might not want to run with the testing repositories, then simply remove it from the sources. The testing repositories gives you more recent updates of several packages, but is not considered stable.

Comment: Again, modifying the `hosts` file is a *highly* suboptimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hijacking old topic, but faced with the same problem recently. So, based on the advice given above and the output of **host** and **whois**:

```
# host security.debian.org
security.debian.org has address 212.211.132.250
security.debian.org has address 195.20.242.89
security.debian.org has address 212.211.132.32
security.debian.org has IPv6 address 2001:8d8:580:400:6564:a62:0:2
security.debian.org has IPv6 address 2001:a78:5:0:216:35ff:fe7f:be4f
security.debian.org has IPv6 address 2001:a78:5:1:216:35ff:fe7f:6ceb
```

Solved problem in a slightly different way - lowered the precedence of the IPv6 networks which contain *security.debian.org* in */etc/gai.conf*:

```
# Make IPv6 for security.debian.org undesirable
precedence 2001:8d8:580::/48    5
precedence 2001:a78:5::/48      5
```

So, IPv6 is still preferred except for *security.debian.org*.

Answer (score -2):

I have found a much better way to do this. Open up your `sources.list` file and note down the hostnames of the repos. Get their *IPv4* addresses, then edit `sources.list` with the IPv4 addresses rather than the hostnames. Apt-get should now contact the repositories over the IPv4 addresses you specified, bypassing IPv6.

There is the disadvantage that repos usually have some sort of load balancing and/or IP geolocation set up, which this method of course bypasses. However, it shouldn't matter if only a few people are doing it. If you do find one mirror is slow, try getting another repo IP address (for instance, by using an online ping service) and use that.

Comment: That's a really bad solution, actually, for the reasons you already describe.