# Force getaddrinfo to use IPv4

Tags: linux, socket

The man page says:

> The getaddrinfo(3) function is not limited to creating IPv4 socket
>   address structures; IPv6 socket address structures can be created if
>   IPv6 support is available.  These socket address structures can be
>   used directly by bind(2) or  connect(2), to prepare a client or a
>   server socket.

What should I do to force `getaddrinfo` to *not* create IPv6 socket address structures?

Comment: Is this for a program you're writing? Or are you trying to get an application that calls `getaddrinfo` with `AF_UNSPEC` not to use IPv6?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, [the first question I ever asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method) on this site turned out to have an answer you might find useful.

To summarize, the file `/etc/gai.conf` is used by the getaddrinfo() system call to determine how to respond. For your particular case, adding

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

to the end of the config file should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my CentOS 5.5 final, there is no /etc/gai.conf, do I need to create one?

Comment: Possibly. According to `dpkg` the file is part of the `libc-bin` package, which is pretty deep down the essential packages list in Debian...

Answer (score 1):

According to the manpage for `getaddrinfo()`, you can pass the address family in the `hints` parameter, so something like

```
struct addrinfo hints, *result;
int s;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;        /* or AF_INET6 for ipv6 addresses */
s = getaddrinfo(NULL, "ftp", &hints, &result);
...
```

I haven't tried this, but the approach seems to be right.