# Apt hanging when updating non-free Translation-en (Debian Stretch)

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to run a normal update so that I can install some other packages. However whenever I run it apt-get hangs on:

```
 Get:26 http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ stretch/non-free Translation-en [79.2 kB] 
 0% [Working]
```

I originally had an iinet mirror, and I even switched to the main ftp.debian.org one. Neither worked.

I've cleared temp data with:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

but it still hangs!

I've removed apt-get with

```
dpkg --force-depends --purge apt
```

and then reinstalled it by downloading the apt package from Debian's website but still no dice.

What could possibly be causing it to not do a simple update procedure?

---

**Update 1**

I have made it ignore Tranlsations-en by following [the selected answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74653/how-can-i-remove-the-translation-entries-in-apt). Now it hangs on:

```
Get:21 http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ stretch/main i386 Packages [7,074 kB]
```

---

**Update 2**

Based off a few other [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method) I tried to force apt-get to only use IPv4 addresses as this apparently can solve hanging problems.

```
 sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
```

No dice.

---

**Update 3**

I manually installed aptitude alongside apt-get using dpkg. However

```
sudo aptitude update
```

ALSO hangs! At the same place. Except it displays 100% rather than 0%...

```
Get: 24 http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ stretch/non-free Translation-en [79.2 kB]
100% [Working]
```

Answer (score 5):

Alrighty. So I'm not really sure why but deleting everything in:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Fixed it. Even though the only things in there were source list extras for mendeley and sublime-text.

Sigh.

Comment: I confirm this.... inside this folder are added repositories which may not work with time... and as OP said after deleting them (I made mv command to have backup) apt get update worked!

Comment: After several hours trying to torubleshoot apt i finally found this reference and had the same results, a mariadb.list in the sources.d folder was holding it up for some reason..